# Excel 2010 while setting autofilter poi

Tags: apache-poi

```
HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(); 
HSSFSheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Excel"); 
sheet.setAutoFilter(CellRangeAddress.valueOf("A1:P1")); //As I am using excel 2010 version
```

I am getting the following alert while opening the excel sheet:

[image: while using autofilter in Excel 2007 it is opening properly]

Comment: Do you get the alert from other versions of Excel? If you open the file anyway, and do a save-as, does that fix it? If so, how does the file then differ?

Comment: Gagravarr -  In excel 2003 we didnt get this alert.When we migrated this version 2010 we are getting this alert while opening first time.

Comment: still i didn't solve my problem.answers are accepted